# Easy installation method for windows/ Batch Reference needed?

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation

I have a bunch of files that I need to be able to *transport* and *install* quickly. My current method for doing so is moving a flash drive with a readme file of where stuff goes whenever I need to move stuff, which is rather inelegant and cumbersome.

My idea for a solution would be to write up a quick script to move files around that I could just click on. I've done some ***bash*** scripting before but ***batch*** scripting is a little odd to me. Does anyone have a good online reference guide I could use?

An alternative soulution I could accept would be a program that makes an installer for you, though I'm a bit against that as I would lose a lot of control. However, I'd be alright with it if it was extremely simple,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `robocopy` tool is exactly what you need.
Very *powerful* replication command-line tool.

- [MS TechNet reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145),
- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) about `robocopy`,
- Full command switch [guide](http://atlex.nl/tmp/robocopy_switches.txt),
- Batch scripting [guide](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=307).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use VBscript for this kind of thing.  The VBS engine is on every recent windows machine and the language is a little more like real programming than a batch script.

Also, if your installer grows to require WMI functions too, this becomes a piece of cake.